# Executing files directly from read/write WebDAV server

Tags: terminal, finder, webdav

I’m using the Finder’s built-in `Connect to Server...` feature and use it for connecting to a read/write WebDAV server. Everything is working except executing files hosted on the server. I tried mounting the server using the `mount_webdav` Terminal command, and got the same result as using the Finder. Running `ls -laF /Volumes/webdav` results in:

```
drwx------  1 myname  staff    2048 Mar 15 14:09 ./
drwxrwxrwt  4 root    admin     170 Mar 15 09:25 ../
-rwx------  ...
drwx------  ...
-rwx------  ...
drwx------  ...
...
```

Which makes me assume that files should be executable. However, executing a bash script from the server in Terminal results in:

```
bash: /Volumes/webdav/test.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I just want to be able to execute these files without having to move them to a physical disk. What am I overlooking?

EDIT: per request of @patrix, here are the commands i used:

```
mkdir /Volumes/webdav
mount_webdav -i -s https://example.com/program/ /Volumes/webdav/
chmod +x /Volumes/webdav/test.sh
head /Volumes/webdav/test.sh
/Volumes/webdav/test.sh
```

and the output was:

```
#mount_webdav
Username: ‹username›
Password: 
# head
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /tmp/tex
cd /tmp/tex
cp -RX /Volumes/webdav/tex/* .
xelatex report.tex
open report.pdf
# exec
bash: /Volumes/webdav/test.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you run `head /Volumes/webdav/test.sh` and `mount`, then add the output of both to the question?

Comment: OP updated! The bash script works as intended when I copy it to the system disk. The issue *has* to be related to the server volume.

Comment: Can you just run `mount` without any options and include the output as well? The volume could be mounted with a "noexec" option set.

Comment: I have the same problem, and yes, the volume is mounted noexec. Is there any way to prevent that?