# how to mount distant webdav resource from command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, ventura, webdav

I'm on macos ventura 13.4, Intel processor.

I can use `https://somelogin@server.work/webdav/somelogin` using the Finder "Connect to server" menu. (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>). No problem at all.

Now, I'm a terminal guy, and I'd like to open this location in Finder from the command line. So far, I've tried:

*

```
open -a Finder https://somelogin@server.work/webdav/somelogin
```

but this tries to open the URL in my browser :-(

- Use `mkdir` and `mount_webdav`as shown on [ask different #176819](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/176810/389822)

  ```
  mkdir /Volumes/somelogin 
  mount_webdav -i https://somelogin@server.work/webdav/somelogin /Volumes/somelogin
  ```

  but `mkdir` is denied access to /Volumes: `mkdir: /Volumes/somelogin: Permission denied`
- tried to mount the davfs on some dir in my home

  ```
  mkdir ~/somelogin 
  mount_webdav -i https://somelogin@server.work/webdav/somelogin ~/somelogin
  ```

  I'm prompted for the username and password but then, without any message `mount_webdav` exits with error code 22.

How can I either mount the resource somewhere from command line or tell Finder or any other app to mount it under /Volumes for me ? (even `osascript "tell something to mount that webdav resource"` would be ok)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: switching from terminal to Finder is a disturbance I'd like to avoid. I'm trying to have that webdav volume mounted without leaving the terminal. How exactly this is performed does not matter, so long as it can be done from terminal.